# Creating interaction terms from two matrices

Tags: r, matrix

Let's say I have two matrices:

```
w <- data.frame(w1 = rnorm(10), w2 = rnorm(10), w3 = rnorm(10), w4 = rnorm(10))
x <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(10), x2 = rnorm(10), x3 = rnorm(10), x4 = rnorm(10))
```

I want to produce a matrix wx which has columns

`w1x1, w1x2, w1x3, w1x4, w2x1, w2x2, ... , w4x4`

Each column is simply the product of two columns, one from each matrix. For example, `w1x1` is simply the product of `w1` and `x1`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
res <- apply(w, 2, function(i) { 
    i * x
    })

wx <- do.call(cbind, res)
```